# How to reduce size of app through pro-guard in ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am trying to reduce size of my ionic app through pro-guard but still app size is same as previous size.Please anyone let me known, how to reduce size of app through pro-guard.

Comment: use cordova-proguard-plugin

Answer (score 0):

There is easy no way to reduce the cordova app size.

You must reduce the resources size inorder to reduce the app size.
Or you can manually minify the HTML,JS and CSS files for better performance.

You can use [TINY PNG](https://tinypng.com/)  to reduce the image's file size. Images use most of app's size.

Good Day!

Comment: As  im using ionic in almost all my apps. Im reducing the apk size by reducing the resources size manually :)

Comment: Sorry. there isnt any other tools. 
Now a days app size are not a big deal